# Don't submit form when I press enter key in a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, validation, textbox

i have a text-box in my form. I write a `JavaScript`  function to add some functionality when user enter some value in text box and then press `Enter` button. When I press `Enter` button, first , it perform my JavaScript functionality but then it shows the validations message(it submits the form). How to solve this problem

Here is my texbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_CopyFrom" runat="server" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here is my JavaScript function

```
function searchKeyPress(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                .
                .
                .

        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prevent the default action by using `preventDefault()`

```
function searchKeyPress(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            .
            .
            .

    }
    return false;
}
```